# SQL how can i get only those users from the database that have the term_Date >=60

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a database in SQL that has lot of columns.I want to select only those users that have the term_Date (column)>=60
The format of term_Date is yyyy-MM-dd
The main goal is to delete later the users the date of which in term_Date was 2months before( so 60 days approximately). For example, one of the users would be one that has the term_Date 2022-08-01
Note:there is no any column with the Today Date in this DB.

If this can help

```
User_TERMINATION
term_date(nvarchar(max),null)
ident(PK,nchar(30),Not null)
voluntary(nchar(5),null)
first_name(nvarchar(max),null)
```

Comment: "The format of term_Date is..." -- are you saving your dates as string? Can you clarify, what DB you use, the column data types, etc.

Comment: its varchar the inf saved in the column term_Date.

Comment: Please Edit your question and provide all necessary info to answer it. If you have a table then provide full or partial table definition. Provide database specifics. If date is saved as string, this is BAD.

Comment: I just edited it :) hope the edit will help

Comment: `Delete from user_termination where getdate() - CONVERT(datetime, term_date, 102) >= 60`. In sql server `date1 - date2` returns days

Comment: Well Guys the solution of what I waned to take is this : Select *
from User_TERMINATION
where DATEDIFF(day,term_date,GETDATE() )>=60 I think I had explained in a confusing way to you, I needed to take those users that have the term_date older or equal than 60days starting from the current date.

Comment: `term_date` is a varchar so its success right now is based on how globalization setting is set on the server. Hence, moved to some other server it might not work as you currently have it. First, convert the string to date

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
    WHERE term_Date>=now()-interval 2 month
```

You can refer this link too
https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/date-lastweek.php

Comment: How can you answer if you don't even know many details about the DB and columns?

Comment: i have posted only general answer to this question

Comment: In order to take those that have the term_Date=Today I am using this code
////////////Select*
from User_TERMINATION
WHERE term_Date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

/////////////now, I need those who have the term_Date 60 days less or equal from the today date

Comment: `now()` is not generic at all, I think it may be only in MySql.

Comment: @Andrew Moreover, the OP posted code with `GETDATE()`, so it is more like SQL Server

Comment: @YanniGoel see new comments. your answer is becoming invalid as more information is coming. I wouldn't bother answering something that does not have enough information.

Comment: @T.S. OK next time i will answer good questions with appropriate information

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).